# Compile apk with custom values triggered by online web form

Tags: android, apache, compilation, server, apk

I have created a simple Android App that contains website URLs and different images -they are hardcoded in the App. I will upload the raw files (not APK) in an Ant Apache run server online to serve as template files. I am in the process of creating a website with a form that asks user to complete fields that replace aspects of the Android App that I have built, such as images and URL fields (websites). After user clicks "Submit", I want all of the user input fields to replace the respective fields in the template files. From the resources I've found online, a command line can be used to compile the RAW android files into an APK, but I don't know how to do this using an online server as I want this process to be automated and "on command" when a user fills out the form online to obtain a link to download their custom APK.

How am I able to run this build command triggered by user input on an online form and with the output of a newly generated APK with the user's input replacing .xml files and images of the App?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to develop an application that uses User input from a website and gives it to the APK
You can use

```
<receiver android:name=".ABroadCastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In this broadcast receiver you can get all the values entered by user:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null)
        return;
    Log.d("Values[]", intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY"));
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
    i.putExtra("value1", value[0]);
    i.putExtra("value2", value[1]);
    startActivity(i);
```

In Activity you can use

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.getStringExtra("value1");
i.getStringExtra("value2");
```

**NOTE : com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER is the intent that is passed to the application when it is installed from the Google Play Store**

The link you will create should look like this

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%3CYOUR_PACKAGE_NAME%3E&YOUR_KEY=value1.value2.value3
```

Comment: The functionality that compiles the files into an APK and provides a download link will all simply be a website that users will go to. For example, a user goes to www.mysite.com and immediately see a form to fill out with their custom links and images to be replaced in the App that is not yet compiled. Then, after hitting "Submit", the functionality that you mentioned should run in the background of the website and provide the APK. Is the functionality that you provided me able to be run on a website?

Comment: I know my question can get complicated but here is a link to what I want to build exactly, sometimes visuals help best illustrate my question: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTmMQ3tAN_4)